# get unique records from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, chat

[image]

Please check this query. Actually, I want to fetch only two records, not 4 records. I should get last record per from_member_id and to_member_id. Currently, I get two records for it. Please let me know what I am doing wrong in the query

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT from_member_id, to_member_id
  FROM `single_chat`
 where from_member_id = 175 or to_member_id = 175
 group by from_member_id, to_member_id
```

Desired output

```
175 176
175 177
```

Comment: which 2 records should come in your output? Please add the desired output in text form in the question.

Comment: Read and apply: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @AkhileshMishra desired output added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below - **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fab8929e30165df715eafc4f852cfc7f)**

```
SELECT distinct
   t2.from_member_id,t2.to_member_id
FROM single_chat t1
     JOIN single_chat t2 on t1.from_member_id=t2.to_member_id 
     and t1.to_member_id < t2.to_member_id 
where t1.from_member_id = 175 or t1.to_member_id = 175
```

OUTPUT:

```
f_id    t_id
175     176
175     177
```

Comment: I get this when I run your query: https://prnt.sc/vh6tsx
can you please check this?

Comment: @user3886556, updated the answer - you can check now

Comment: works perfectly: https://prnt.sc/vh81lr
Thank you so much